# Python decorators and side-effects

Tags: python, python-decorators

Recently I stumbled upon a slight difference in how a Python decorator behaves depending on whether [functools wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is used or not.

Without `functools`, this would be an example (trivial) decorator that just takes a single argument and prints it before calling the wrapped function

```py
def order(arg):
    def wrapper(func):
        print(f"order: {arg}")
        return func

    return wrapper


@order("one")
@order("two")
def inc(x):
    return x + 1


print(inc(7))
#Output:
# order: two
# order: one
# 8
```

With `functools.wraps` the code would be

```py
from functools import wraps


def order(arg):
    def outer_wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"order: {arg}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner_wrapper

    return outer_wrapper


@order("one")
@order("two")
def inc(x):
    return x + 1


print(inc(7))
#Output:
# order: one
# order: two
# 8
```

Subtle difference but the order of side-effects (in this case the `print` statement) is reversed and unless the engineer using the decorator digs into the implementation detail of the decorator, there is no way of knowing how it will show up.
Is there a way for the *decorator's implementor* can avoid this ambiguity?

Comment: I suspect this is related to the extra level of `inner_wrapper()`.

Comment: I don’t think the first snippet is a decorator.

Comment: Sure it's a decorator, it just returns the original function unmodified. That's useful sometimes, with decorators that, say, `register` a function to receive callbacks.

Comment: more nested wrapper function you make, you need to see how argument are going inside, ie as it for FILO order (my observation only) correct me if i am wrong. first it is `1,2` then `2, 1` and then `1, 2`  and so on

Answer (score 1):

It might help you understand what is going on if you added some additional `print` statements in your code. Your two versions of the decorator are currently printing out at very different times, but that's obscured a bit because of the limited number of print statements. With a few more, you'll understand things better. Here's an updated version of the second version of your code.

```
def order(arg):
    print(f"order: {arg}")
    def outer_wrapper(func):
        print(f"outer_wrapper: {arg}")
        @wraps(func)
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"inner_wrapper: {arg}")
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print(f"inner_wrapper, after function call: {arg}")
            return result

        return inner_wrapper

    return outer_wrapper


@order("one")
@order("two")
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

print("after function definition")

print(inc(7))
```

The output will be:

```
order: one
order: two
outer_wrapper: two
outer_wrapper: one
after function definition
inner_wrapper: one
inner_wrapper: two
inner_wrapper, after function call: two
inner_wrapper, after function call: one
8
```

The first version of your code only prints out at the same time this code prints the `outer_wrapper` messages, and the second version of your code only prints out the `inner_wrapper` messages (the ones before the function call, not the ones after). Note that some of the messages print out when the function is *defined* (and the decorators are applied) and others print out later, when the function is *called* (and will print again if you call the function additional times).

Comment: I'm referring to the `inc` definition, not to the decorator's definition.